# ID with Javascript doesn't work as needed

Tags: javascript, raphael

in Raphaeljs, it wrote this line of code:(only relevant part is shown)

```
......
    sets.id = index;
    grid.hex[poly].click(
      function(e)
    {   
        var id=this.id
.....
```

It sets the id of the sets[] properly, but the id of "this" is the id of the path inside of the sets, the one that was clicked. I have to have the id of the sets. How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT:
I want "this" to be sets, not the path that was clicked.**

Comment: Isn’t `index` available as is inside the handler because of closures?

Comment: this is inside a function, sets is inside an array, and there are a lot of thing that aren't relevant that I didn't include.  I can't use index as it is.

Comment: `var id=sets.id`? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: nope, because there is array of sets.. not just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind function to `sets`

```
......
    sets.id = index;
    grid.hex[poly].click($.proxy(function(e){
         var id = this.id;
    }, sets);
.....
```

Or if you are not using jQuery.

```
//https://gist.github.com/978329
if(!Function.prototype.bind) {
   Function.prototype.bind = function(to){
        // Make an array of our arguments, starting from second argument
    var partial = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1),
        // We'll need the original function.
        fn  = this;
    var bound = function (){
        // Join the already applied arguments to the now called ones (after converting to an array again).
        var args = partial.concat(Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0));
        // If not being called as a constructor
        if (!(this instanceof bound)){
            // return the result of the function called bound to target and partially applied.
            return fn.apply(to, args);
        }
        // If being called as a constructor, apply the function bound to self.
        fn.apply(this, args);
    }
    // Attach the prototype of the function to our newly created function.
    bound.prototype = fn.prototype;
    return bound;

}

grid.hex[poly].click(function(e){
         var id = this.id;
    }.bind(sets));
```

Comment: I'm confused, why did write this line? : var setID=id;?

Comment: To make current index available inside your click handler.

Comment: gives me the same, after clicking the path it it gives me the path instead of the set as "this"

Comment: 'I have to have the id of the sets'. Well, you have it via `setId`. Just use it instead of `this.id`. If you want `this` to be sets, plz correct your question.

Comment: Updated to bind handler to `sets`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
var id = this.parentElement.id
```

**UPDATE:**

From http://raphaeljs.com/:

> Raphaël ['ræfeɪəl] uses the SVG W3C Recommendation and VML as a base
>   for creating graphics. **This means every graphical object you create
>   is also a DOM object**, so you can attach JavaScript event handlers or
>   modify them later.

Assuming `sets` is a graphical object (and since it contains paths, I assume it is), then `this` should have a `parentElement` property to access.

If it doesn't work, you could also try accessing it as:

```
var id = sets.id;
```

which should work because of the closure.

Comment: doesn't parentElement works for DOM only? set isn't a part of the DOM